How to handle circular dependecy between two tables in SQLAlchemy
I'm having a problem resolving a circular dependency between two tables.  Have followed all the information I found, but it still doesn't quite work.
My tables look like this
             run                                                calibration_metric
-------------------------------------------           ---------------------------------
run_pk         calibration_metric_pk                    calibration_metric          run_pk
   1                     5                                      5                     1

The relationship from calibration_metric to run is many to 1, but from run to calibration_metric is 1 to 1
I have the following definitions (extraneous fields removed)
lass Run(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'run'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    calibration_metric_pk = mapped_column(ForeignKey("calibration_metric.pk", name="fk_run_calibration_metric"))
    metric = relationship("CalibrationMetric",
                                 primaryjoin="calibration_metric_pk == CalibrationMetric.pk",
                                 post_update=True)

lass CalibrationMetric(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'calibration_metric'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    run_pk = mapped_column(ForeignKey("run.pk", name="fk_calibration_metric_run"))
    run = relationship("Run")

I have this section, "objective_metric_pk == CalibrationMetric.pk", in quotes because without them, Python complained about circular import
I'm getting this error
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Run(run)], expression 'calibration_metric_pk == CalibrationMetric.pk' failed to locate a name ("name 'calibration_metric_pk' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'root.db.models.Run.Run'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
I can't figure out why it's not finding the calibration_metric_pk
Note that I don't care about getting the list of Calibration_Metric objects in Run, that are associated by the Run primary key.  I only care about the 1-1 relationship and getting the Calibration_Metric object pointed to by the calibration_metric_pk field.
But I would also like to have access to the Run object from Calibration_Metric.run_pk.  I don't think I need to specify back_populates, since I only care about 1 end of each of the relationships

It makes no sense to have many-to-1 in one direction, but 1-to-1 in the other direction. You only need a FK in calibration_metric, not run.

Yeah, the naming is confusing.   Maybe it is to specify a special one out of the many.   Hard to tell if it is intentional or not.

Correct. There are 2 separate relationships. There are multiple calibration metrics, and then there is a special one, of which there is just 1

The relationship from calibration_metrics to run.pk is 1 to many in one direction and many to one in the other as one would expect. There is a separate relationships that is 1-1. This is the one defined by calibration_metrics_pk in the Run table

It might work:
class Run(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'run'
    pk = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    calibration_metric_pk = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey("calibration_metric.pk", name="fk_run_calibration_metric"))
    metric = relationship(
        "CalibrationMetric", foreign_keys=[calibration_metric_pk],
                                 post_update=True)

class CalibrationMetric(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'calibration_metric'
    pk = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    run_pk = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey("run.pk", name="fk_calibration_metric_run"), )
    run = relationship("Run", foreign_keys=[run_pk])

The param foreign_keys=[] was missing

Try primaryjoin="Run.calibration_metric_pk == CalibrationMetric.pk".  I think in cases where you mentioned the column without the class it is actually using the column from within the class declaration scope. When using the late evaluation that doesn't work, ie. when quoting.

It was a combination of explicitly specifying Run.calibration_metric_pk, as well as needing the foreign_keys specification
